# Можно-ли отренедрить переданный DOM элемент в шаблоне для lodash

Tags: javascript, шаблоны, lodash

Здравствуйте! Можно-ли отренедрить переданный DOM элемент в шаблоне для lodash 
создаю объект элемента формы и передаю в шаблон:

```
let html = _.template(baseTemplate)({ formAdd });
document.write(html);
```

И сам шаблон:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 text-center inBlock">
   <%- formAdd%>
</div>
```